# Giving height to table and row in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 , i am trying to give height to `table` and `row`, but nothing is working for me .

I tried setting `line-height` and other properties of table, how can I increase height?

```
<style>
    div#description {
        background-color: gray;
        height: 25%;
        border: 2px black;
    }
    tr {
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .container {
        height: 100%
    }
    table {
        height: 100%
    }
    #topics tr {
        line-height: 14px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-10 pull-left">
                <p>Hello</p>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered ">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-8 pull-right" id="description">
                <p>Hello2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 38):

For the `<tr>`'s just set

```css
tr {
   line-height: 25px;
   min-height: 25px;
   height: 25px;
}
```

It works with bootstrap also. For the `100%` height, `100%` must be 100% of *something*. Therefore, you must define a fixed height for one of the containers, or the body. I guess you want the entire page to be 100%, so (example) :

```css
body {
    height: 700px;
}
.table100, .row, .container, .table-responsive, .table-bordered  {
    height: 100%;
}
```

A workaround not to set a static height is by forcing the height in code according to the viewport :

```js
$('body').height(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

all the above in this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LZuJt/**

**Note** : I do not care that you have `25%` height on `#description`, and `100%` height on table. Guess it is just an example. And notice that `clientHeight` is not right since the documentElement is an iframe, but you'll get the picture in your own projekt :)

Comment: Instead of using js to set the body height you could use 100vh (vh -  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 9):

**CSS**:

```
tr {
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
height:60px;                // <-- the rows height 
}

table{
 height:300px;              // <-- Select the height of the table
 display: -moz-groupbox;    // For firefox bad effect
}
tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;      
  height: 200px;            //  <-- Select the height of the body
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/AgI8LpDugl

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution that worked for me as below, wrap the table with a div and change the `line-height`, this line-height is taken as a ratio.

```html
<div class="col-md-6" style="line-height: 0.5">
                                <table class="table table-striped" >
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Parameter</th>
                                        <th>Recorded Value</th>
                                        <th>Individual Score</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Respiratory Rate</td>
                                        <td>Doe</td>
                                        <td>john@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Respiratory Effort</td>
                                        <td>Moe</td>
                                        <td>mary@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Oxygon Saturation</td>
                                        <td>Dooley</td>
                                        <td>july@example.com</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Try changing the value as it fits for you.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was adding a div around the content.
Originally i had this.  Css applied to the td had no effect.

```
        <td>           
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)           
        </td>
```

Then I wrapped the content in a div and the css worked as expected

```
       <td>
            <div class="largeContent">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
            </div>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gfgux

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#table-row, #table-col, #table-wrapper {
    height: 80%;
}

<div id="content" class="container">
    <div id="table-row" class="row">
        <div id="table-col" class="col-md-7 col-xs-10 pull-left">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <div id="table-wrapper" class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered ">
```