# Set the height of bootstrap td table into minimum

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have tried

[How to set maximum height for table-cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667941/how-to-set-maximum-height-for-table-cell)

[giving height to table and row in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612535/giving-height-to-table-and-row-in-bootstrap)

[How to set the size of a column in a Bootstrap responsive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385289/how-to-set-the-size-of-a-column-in-a-bootstrap-responsive-table)

But none of this type are seems to work for me..

my table is just looks like this

```css
  .table {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.table tr td {
   height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
tr {
   line-height: 5px;
   min-height: 5px;
   height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table  class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Ket</th>
      <th colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</th>
      <th colspan="3">TP yang ditindak lanjuti (TP)</th>
      <th rowspan="2">TPB s/d Bulan Ini</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</th>
      <th>TP Bulan ini</th>
      <th>TP s/d Bulan ini</th>
      <th>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</th>
      <th>TP Bulan ini</th>
      <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">01</td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >10</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>55.950.000</td>
        <td>55.950.000</td>
        <td>86.900.000</td>
        <td>10.000.000</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>10.000.000</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">0101</td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>18.000.000</td>
        <td>18.000.000</td>
        <td>27.000.000</td>
        <td>10.000.000</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>10.000.000</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">0102</td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>16.950.000</td>
        <td>16.950.000</td>
        <td>17.900.000</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">0103</td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>21.000.000</td>
        <td>21.000.000</td>
        <td>42.000.000</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">02</td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >7</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>26.000.000</td>
        <td>26.000.000</td>
        <td>26.000.000</td>
        <td>46.000.000</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>46.000.000</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">0201</td>
        <td>Kejadian</td>
        <td >1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td  rowspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      </tr>
       </tbody>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">TOTAL</td>
      <td>Kejadian</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
         <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

THere is some people said that you have to use `<div>` tag. Is it possible for didnt use that ?

**What i want to achieve is, make the td row looks more smaller**

**( e.g the table row height is `5px` if possible )**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should adjust table row and table data [alive demo](https://jsfiddle.net/farghly/fjwamynw/2/)

```
.table {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.table tr,.table td {
   height: 10px;
   text-align: center
}

.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th
{
  padding:0; 
}
```

remove padding If you want to do row more smaller
if you give `font size 14px height will take 14px` 
`bootstrap` add padding to table `padding:8px;` remove this `padding`

Comment: i wnat to make the table row more smaller

Comment: remove `padding` I update my answer to your question and add `alive demo` to my answer

Comment: note that i am using bootstrap.. is this would work ?

Comment: I know this and test my answer with alive demo https://jsfiddle.net/farghly/fjwamynw/2/